# How to select alternative rows from table in sql?

Tags: sql

In table there is a column named status which can have either 1 or 2.
Now I want to select pattern like this

```
First Row 1
Second Row 2
Third Row 1
Fourth Row 2
......
```

Comment: Terms such as "first", "second" etc. don't have a meaning unless you define an ordering. What's your ordering?

Answer (score 2):

For even rows

```
select * from emp where rowid%2 = 0;
```

For odd rows

```
select * from emp where rowid%2 != 0;
```

Comment: As per question value need to be sorted based on value in column status. What if status values 1 and 1 are at row ID 1 and 2  ? This query will give wrong result.

Answer (score 1):

### Oracle:

```
 SELECT * from
    ( SELECT a1.*,rank() over (partition BY status order by rownum) RNK FROM TABLE1 a1
     )
    ORDER BY rnk,status
```

***[Sqlfiddle:](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f0d1/1)***

Answer (score 1):

### MS SQL:

```
select t1.*, (RN % 2)+1 as [STATUS] from
(
  select t.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <ORDER COLUMN NAME HERE>) as RN
) t1
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select * from (select table.* ,rownum k from table) where mod(k,2)<>0;
```

Comment: It also adds extra column named `k`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
SELECT e1.* FROM Employee e1
INNER JOIN  
(
    Select e2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY <Column Names>) AS RN FROM Employee e2

)E2 
ON e1.eid=e2.eid
where e2.RN%2=0
```

Answer (score 0):

TO Get ODD records use following:

```
SELECT e1.* FROM Employee e1 INNER JOIN
( Select e2.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ) AS RN FROM Employee e2 )E2 ON e1.eid=e2.eid where e2.RN%2=1
```