# Get the alternate rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `PERSON` with a single column `GENDER`, and values in 6 rows is like:

```
GENDER

M
M
M
F
F
F
```

The output should be like

```
GENDER

M
F
M
F
M
F
```

What should be the SQL query to get such output? I believe `ROWNUMBER()` must be used.

Comment: what if the no of rows for M and F are different ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select alternative rows from table in sql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14040865/how-to-select-alternative-rows-from-table-in-sql)

Comment: The question is like there are 2 values in table having same no. of rows for those 2 values, already grouped. The output should have same no. of records but the records should be alternate from 2 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT GENDER, R = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY GENDER ORDER BY GENDER)
FROM   PERSON
ORDER BY R, GENDER DESC
```